# OpenOffice.org installation image does not mount

Tags: macos, mac, openoffice

The newest OpenOffice.org v3.1.1 does not want to mount on my Mac. It just says it couldn't.

I have 10.5.4.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's the US English version for Intel, then compare the output of the following with the results for your DMG. If it doesn't match then you need to download again.

```
md5 ~/Downloads/OOo_3.1.1_MacOSXIntel_install_en-US.dmg

  MD5([..]) = d20e8ad6f0d8e93860f1ea2cd2371c86
```

A link to [checksums for other downloads](http://download.openoffice.org/md5sums/) can be found at [the download page](http://download.openoffice.org/).

Comment: +1 checking MD5 or SHA1 checksums is highly recommended for downloads like this

Comment: OK it's corrupt. I got a totally different one, efe07e22a3c6f79dfac6e85e753f3cf0.

Comment: It *could* be different if it is a different file (like different version, language and so on), but given your problems I assume the download indeed failed. The list of all 3.1.1 checksums can be found at http://download.openoffice.org/md5sums/3.1.1_md5sums.txt but yours is not listed.

Comment: No, that's not the prob. it is indeed perfectly the same file as you have entered in your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [PowerISO](http://www.poweriso.com/download.htm). Scroll down to "Other Downloads" and download PowerISO for OSX.

Answer (score 0):

If you still can't mount the dmg, rebuild Launch Services by trashing the following two files in the Macintosh HD > Library > Caches folder: com.apple.LaunchServices-0140.csstore and com.apple.LaunchServices-014nnn.csstore  The "nnn" in the second file name is going to be your User ID number, but that probably doesn't matter.

Restart and OS X will rebuild Launch Services.